# location.hash prevents page load in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Test case:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
setInterval(function (){
    window.location.hash='#hash'+Math.random()
},400);
</script>
<a href="http://google.com/">click me</a>
```

(if you have too fast connection, set interval to lower value)

In Chrome 17.0.963.66 `window.location.href` prevents page load when clicking a link, while in Firefox 10.0.2 everything works as expected. Is it a bug or not? Is there any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for me it is not a bug. Chrome begins loading of google.com and in load process interval-function changes url back to old one (http://mysite.com#hash123123) and chrome breaks google.com loading and loads new url(http://mysite.com#hash123123)

Workaround for this case - add onClick handler for <a> and in this handler stop interval